# Opening serial connection to Arduino through Bash

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port, arduino

I have set up my Arduino so when I send a "0" via the serial monitor, a stepper motor turns a given amount.

I want to include this in a bash script, but I can only get this to work when the arduino serial monitor is open and entering `echo 0 > /dev/tty.usbserial641` in bash. I assume this is because serial monitor is opening the connection for me.

In my struggle to open the connection in bash (without serial monitor open) I have tried all manner of options with `stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial641` and have also tried connecting reset to ground with a 10uF capacitor.

Can any help me open the connection in bash without the use of arduino serial monitor?

System:
Arduino Uno rev3
OS X 10.8.4

Many thanks,
hcaw

Answer (score 5):

Do the commands below work for you.

```
 # stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb
 # sleep 0.1
 # echo "0" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

There is a difference between the value 0 and the ascii char 0 (48). Which one you trying to send, and which one are you trying to receive?

If you want to read the port from the terminal you can do it like this

```
head -n 1 /dev/ttyUSB0  //the number after n is how many lines you want to read
```

As a last note, I am a fan of [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/). I would much rather write an interface in python than shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I found a great binary written in C that solves my problem called Arduino-serial. Here's [the link.](http://todbot.com/blog/2013/04/29/arduino-serial-updated/)
I hope this helps people with similar problems!

Comment: I should add, you will need that 10uF cap between reset & ground in order to stop the Arduino auto-resetting every time you send a string over serial :)